# ReactJS: Global Okta Auth Helper Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, okta-signin-widget

I have my React web app authenticated using Okta however if the user is not authenticated or the token expires then it will redirect the user to the `/login` page.

Page1.js:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useOktaAuth } from "@okta/okta-react";
import { Redirect, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const { authState } = useOktaAuth();
const history = useHistory();

useEffect(() => {
    if (!authState) {
      history.push("/login");
    }
});
```

Is there a way I can include the above into an function that I can import to each different Page[#].js instead of including the above code in each file?

Just trying to refactor and make sure my code is tidy as I go but unsure the best way to tackle this.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all the components that required users to be logged in inside a component and protect the routes.

Once the user logs in, set a token in localstorage or redux (you need to persist it). Specify the route to go through IsloggedIn component so that, those routes will only be accessible if user is logged in, else will be redirected to the login page

**Example**

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function IsLoggedIn({ Component, ...props }) {

  const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated");

  return (
    <Route {...props}
      render={(props) =>
        isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
      }
    />
  );
}

export default IsLoggedIn;
```

In App.js

```
function App(){
  return(
    <BrowserRouter>
       <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
       <IsLoggedIn exact path="/" component={Page1} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below

private-route component

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect, RouteProps, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from 'app/config/store';
import { SecureRoute, useOktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-react';
import { authenticationSuccess } from '../reducers/authentication-slice';

export const PrivateRouteComponent = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: IOwnProps) => {
//reducer 
  const isAuthenticated = useAppSelector(state => state.authentication.isOktaAuthenticated);
  const { authState, oktaAuth } = useOktaAuth();

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAuthenticated && authState && authState.isAuthenticated) {
      oktaAuth.token.getUserInfo().then(info => {
//action dispatch
        dispatch(authenticationSuccess({ name: info.name, email: info.email }));
      });
    }
  }, [authState, oktaAuth]); // Update if authState changes

  const renderRedirect = props => {
    return isAuthenticated && <Component {...props} />;
  };

  return <SecureRoute {...rest} render={renderRedirect} />;
};

export default PrivateRouteComponent;
```

in app.js

```
 <Security oktaAuth={oktaAuth} restoreOriginalUri={restoreOriginalUri}>
      <Switch>
            <Route path="/callback" component={LoginCallback} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/home" exact={true} component={Home} />
      </Switch>
  </Security>
```